I am trying to replicate a decision tree from SPSS in python using DecisionTreeClassifier
I am trying to replicate a decision tree from SPSS in python using DecisionTreeClassifier. I am unable to do the following.

Unable to use a feature to do the first force split.
If I use the same variables I do not get a similar model fit. Can We fine tune it without changing the variables or the parameters given already in the model being replicated.
3.Can I score new data on this tree and assign nodes to each row in the new data?
Are there other libraries that I can use that are more flexible?

Any help in this would be really helpful.
I use this bit of code to give same parameters and run the model:
    criterion='gini',  # CART method
    max_depth=5, 
    min_samples_split=100, 
    min_samples_leaf=50
)
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

Model fit is not matching with this model.

would be cool if you could share 1) code from SPSS (including hyperparameters used in CART); 2) metric that you used to compare; 3) What is the metric value for SPSS CART and python CART; 4) did you use same train and validation datasets? Is it possible to share the data. Pls update the question with the responses on the above. thx

Thanks for your response. 1. We cannot share the code because we do not have access to it anymore. 2.The hyperparameters used in the CART are the same as the ones mentioned in the script above. 4. We did use the same training and testing sets. for 3) Do you mean the accuracy, sensitivity etc.?

My view on the question that the result from the SPSS should have very similar accuracy to the one in Python. I don't believe that there could be a reason for big discrepancies.
